# How to store cross application values

Tags: configuration

I have a couple of values that I need to access from multiple programs.  The values are in key value format.

i.e.

```
phone: 733 209 2309
ip address: 111.111.121.111
max-clients: 340
```

Is there a service / protocol that is designed for storing this sort of thing?  I am thinking about using a mysql server and creating a table called configuration; however, if there is a protocol more suited to the task, I would love to learn about it. I want a solution that works well in various different programming languages.

The number of records should be less than 5000.  The values will not normally change (thus fast or simultaneous write is not really necessary). However, fast read speeds is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have decided to go with a mysql Database.  Most languages already support mysql and it responds quickly to requests over a local network.  It still seems like overkill, but I don't know of a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you needs

- multi - simultaneous - write access
- million entrys
- complex trigger

From `gzip` to `postgreSQL`, you could find `SQLite` (maybe the best choice for your need!), `DB` (Berkeley), `OpenOffice Report`, `MySQL`, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated my question with some of your requirement suggestions.